# Python3 ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to run a python code with `torch`.

I am getting

> **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'**

I think I installed the `torch` pakage correctly, but I am facing the same error.

Comment: Check package is installed or not using command: `pip freeze` which gives all installed pakages

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the package by `pip3 uninstall torch`. 
Install it again with `pip3 install torch`. 
Then go to Python shell and import the module by the command:`import torch` .